# Magento 2.1 Add To cart not working on multisite

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have magento 2.1 installed and configured properly to work with 2 different domains using multi-site feature.

Everything works fine, except **Add to cart** feature. Whenever I am adding something to cart on secondary websites, its not being added to cart. However I am getting message that 'Item added to cart'

I checked cookie domain and tried everything, but it is not working

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One of the Reason for product not add to cart if you have not Enable cache.
If cache is disable notification is display 'Item added to cart', but cart does not store product